# Pandas dataframe amount value with dollar symbol

Tags: python, pandas, numeric

I have a pandas dataframe with below columns. Column_1 is string/text and not integer or decimal. Couple of rows have string value as well like Names (refer row no 6)

```
S.No.  Column_1
1      256
2      1
3      $300.54672
4      756
5      $292.34333
6      Andrew
```

I want to convert all values in column_1 to numbers/int, except the dollar values and rows with Names. I require the dollar symbol to be retained but the amount should be rounded to 2 digits after decimal point.

Expected output:

```
S.No.  Column_1
1           256
2             1
3       $300.55
4           756
5       $292.34
6       Andrew
```

I converted entire column to numeric using pd.to_numeric() with errors='coerce' but the amount values became blank (or) null as it was an error.

Any suggestions/help on this would be highly appreciated. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter values starting by `$` by [`Series.str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html), remove `$` by [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html), convert to numeric, round, convert to strings and prepend `$`:

```
m = df['Column_1'].str.startswith('$', na=False)

s = '$' + df.loc[m, 'Column_1'].str.strip('$').astype(float).round(2).astype(str)
```

Or:

```
s = df.loc[m, 'Column_1'].str.strip('$').astype(float).round(2).astype(str).radd('$')

df.loc[m, 'Column_1'] = s


print (df)
   S.No. Column_1
0      1      256
1      2        1
2      3  $300.55
3      4      756
4      5  $292.34
```

Last if need non matched values convert to numeric, but get mixed data types - strings with `$` and numbers without `$`:

```
df.loc[~m, 'Column_1'] = pd.to_numeric(df.loc[~m, 'Column_1'])
print (df)
   S.No.    Column_1
0      1         256
1      2           1
2      3  $300.54672
3      4         756
4      5  $292.34333

print (df['Column_1'].apply(type))
0    <class 'int'>
1    <class 'int'>
2    <class 'str'>
3    <class 'int'>
4    <class 'str'>
Name: Column_1, dtype: object
```

EDIT for last paragraph: Here is possible add `errors='coerce'` for convert non numeric to missing values and then replace them by original:

```
df.loc[~m, 'Column_1'] = pd.to_numeric(df.loc[~m, 'Column_1'], errors='coerce').fillna(df['Column_1'])
print (df)
   S.No. Column_1
0      1      256
1      2        1
2      3  $300.55
3      4      756
4      5  $292.34
5      6   Andrew

print (df['Column_1'].apply(type))

0    <class 'float'>
1    <class 'float'>
2      <class 'str'>
3    <class 'float'>
4      <class 'str'>
5      <class 'str'>
Name: Column_1, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks. Apologies. There is a small problem .Apparently my dataframe has some null values in Column_1 so receiving error while handling Nan or Na values..

Comment: @Padfoot13288 - Here are processing only values string by `$` so it is no problem. Or there is some error?

Comment: Yes.. It cannot process when the series has na values. I am trying with startswith($,na=False). I will keep you posted

Comment: @Padfoot13288 - can you test `m = df['Column_1'].str.startswith('$').fillna(False)` ?

Comment: startswith($,na=False) worked. But other rows except currency are not getting converted to numeric/int (probably because of na values available in column)?

Comment: Thanks Jezrael.. the edited answer is encountering issues because of a string value in the column. Trying a workaround for that

Comment: @Padfoot13288 - Strings are because `$`, unfortunately. Solution is remove them, but not sure if possible

Comment: Its not due to $. Its because another row has string value. Wondering if we can do a work around to handle those too